# Problema ao import bibliotecas do Google no Intelij IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Estou tentando utilizar a API do Google Drive para JAVA porém estou enfrentando problemas na hora de fazer a importação. O código estando funcionando normalmente, porém os meus import estão dando erro. ALguém sabe o que pode esta acontecendo.

Link da documentação que estou seguindo
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/java

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Quem está gerenciando suas libs: Maven, Gradle... você manualmente?

Comment: Estou utilizando o Gradle

Comment: Já tentou executar o Reimport Gradle Project?